# Double Icon on the Ubuntu Unity Desktop dashboard

Tags: unity, icons

Installed qgis from flatpak during the first start it created three icons as shown in the image, of which only one qgis desktop is really the start icon. Wonder how I can delete those two remaining icons that are useless?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the icon and choose `delete icon` ( alt+D,R ).

Comment: unfortunately nothing what you suggest does not work...

Comment: Can anyone suggest me a solution to delete the two useless icons from the dash? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself. Just go to the following path: Home / .local / Share / Application / and delete the icon file corresponding to the program
Thanks anyway